# Add to compare redirects to home page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, url, redirect, compare

I've got this issue.
I'm building a multiwebsite shop with magento 1.9.2.
I've modified the index php to auto detect language and insert language code in url following this:
https://gist.github.com/arosenhagen/5256617

here my index.php version:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2015 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.3.0', '<')===true) {
    echo  '<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
<div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
<h3 style="margin:0; font-size:1.7em; font-weight:normal; text-transform:none; text-align:left; color:#2f2f2f;">
Whoops, it looks like you have an invalid PHP version.</h3></div><p>Magento supports PHP 5.3.0 or newer.
<a href="http://www.magentocommerce.com/install" target="">Find out</a> how to install</a>
 Magento using PHP-CGI as a work-around.</p></div>';
    exit;
}

/**
 * Compilation includes configuration file
 */
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());

$compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/includes/config.php';
if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
    include $compilerConfig;
}

$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
$maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';

if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    if (is_dir('downloader')) {
        header("Location: downloader");
    } else {
        echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    }
    exit;
}

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}

require MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/bootstrap.php';
require_once $mageFilename;

#Varien_Profiler::enable();

if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}

#ini_set('display_errors', 1);

umask(0);
/* Language detection */
function getLanguageCode()
{
    $default_language_code = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
        foreach (explode(",", strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) as $accept) {
            if (preg_match("!([a-z-]+)(;q=([0-9.]+))?!", trim($accept), $found)) {
                $langs[] = $found[1];
                $quality[] = (isset($found[3]) ? (float) $found[3] : 1.0);
            }
        }
        // Order the codes by quality
        array_multisort($quality, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC, $langs);
        // get list of stores and use the store code for the key
        $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        if (strpos($host,'baseDomain') > -1){
            $stores = Mage::app()->getWebsite(1)->getStores(false, true);
            $langPrefix ='r_';
        } elseif (strpos($host,'aliasDomain') > -1) {
            $stores = Mage::app()->getWebsite(2)->getStores(false, true);
            $langPrefix ='a_';
        }
        foreach ($stores as $store) {
            $stores[$store->getCode()] = $store;
        }
        // iterate through languages found in the accept-language header
        foreach ($langs as $lang) {
            $lang = $langPrefix . substr($lang,0,2);
            if (isset($stores[$lang]) && $stores[$lang]->getIsActive()) 
                return $lang;
        }
    }
    return $default_language_code;
}
if ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/it/") !== false ) {
    $url_lang = 'it';
} else if ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/fr/") !== false ) {
    $url_lang = 'fr';
} else if ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/de/") !== false ) {
    $url_lang = 'de';
} else if ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/es/") !== false ) {
    $url_lang = 'es';
} else {
    $url_lang = 'en'; # which is the default language of the default store of your installation (/)
}

$store_code = getLanguageCode();

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = preg_replace("#^/$url_lang(/.*)#i",'$1',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if ( ! preg_match('#^/index.php/admin/#i',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ) {
  $_GET['___store'] = $store_code;
}

/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : $store_code;
/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Now when I add a product to compare list I come redirected to the home page.
After check for this bug I found out this issue come from this function :

```
protected function _getRefererUrl()
{
    $refererUrl = $this->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
    if ($url = $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_REFERER_URL)) {
        $refererUrl = $url;
    }
    if ($url = $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_BASE64_URL)) {
        $refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecodeAndEscape($url);
    }
    if ($url = $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED)) {
        $refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecodeAndEscape($url);
    }

    if (!$this->_isUrlInternal($refererUrl)) {
        $refererUrl = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    }
    return $refererUrl;
}
```

on **app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php**
This function doesn't reconize the refererURL generate by

```
$refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecodeAndEscape($url);
```

as an internal url because the language code disappear:

- expected url : baseDomain/it/productsCategory.html
- given url : baseDomain/productsCategory.html

If i comment out this

```
if ($url = $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED)) {
    $refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecodeAndEscape($url);
}
```

everything works fine but guess could be a big mistake to do so.

So my question is:
How can i get the full path with language code in the encoded url generated by compare link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue modifing getCurrentUrl Function in 
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php on line 53

```
$url = $request->getScheme() . '://' . $request->getHttpHost() . $port . $request->getServer('REQUEST_URI');
```

with

```
$url = $request->getScheme() . '://' . $request->getHttpHost() . $port . '/' . preg_replace('/.*_(.*)/','$1',Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode()) . $request->getServer('REQUEST_URI');
```

with override the file in app/code/local/Mage/Core/Url.php